# Custom JavaScript Exceptions Won't Display Their Messages in Google Chrome's Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with displaying the messages of custom JavaScript exceptions in Google Chrome's console. I'm declaring and throwing my exceptions in the following manner:

```
var Foo = function(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = message;
    this.name = "Foo";
}
Foo.prototype = new Error();
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

throw new Foo("Bar");
```

This works properly in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but in Chrome (v26.0.1410.64 under Windows 8) I'm only getting this message:

> Uncaught [object Object]

What I would expect to get (and what I do get when I throw an instance of **Error**) is something along the lines of this:

> Uncaught Foo: Bar

I have tried disabling all my extensions and overriding the **toString** method to no avail.

Is there anything else I could do to make those messages display properly?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems for the moment it is not fixed / not properly handled by Chrome.

See this issue in Chromium repo: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=228909

Especially, [last comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=228909#c6):

```
function AssertException(message)
{
    "use strict";
    var result = new Error(message);
    result.name = "AssertException";
    return result;
}
```